# Please explain what is the purpose of MIN and STRUCT in below code. Can MIN be added in case statement in HiveQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have newly joined in an organisation and i am facing diificulty in understanding the below code. Can **min** be added to **case statment.** What is the work of **struct** here?

```
case min (if ( breach_flag =1, struct(rank, breach_bucket), null)).col2
                        when 'inbound_staging_breach'
                            then 'mh_breach'
                        when 'bag_closing_breach'
                            then 'mh_breach'
                        when 'tc_breach'
                            then 'tc_breach'
                    end
                ) as breach_bucket_struct
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the struct function is creating a key-value composite like this:

for each value:

{"rank": "breach bucket"}

You are getting the minimum value of these from your Min function.

I didnt understand why you had .col2 at the end on that statement, are you trying to access col2 from the key-value set generated? It seems like there is a syntax error in your statement too.

In summary this is what is happening in your code; you first create a struct when breach_flag is 1, with the values of rank and breach_bucket. Then, it calculates the minimum value, then takes .col2 (which is breach_bucket?) out of it. Based on this value, it returns specific strings ('mh_breach' or 'tc_breach')

If you can provide more context and sample data, I would be able to help properly